# Is it possible to use a VB master page to cover an entirely separate directory written in C#?

Tags: asp.net, c#

I have a company website written in vb.net.  There are 5 master pages.

I recently began utilizing a forum application, also asp.net 4.0, but this one is written in C#.  My forum directory is domain.com/knowledgebase/.

Is there any possible way to take one of my vb.net master pages and somehow integrate into the /knowledgebase/ directory?  Here's what's currently

This is what's in the top of every page in my site:

```
<%@ Page Title="USS Vision Inc." Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/homepage.master" 
AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_default" 
culture="auto" meta:resourcekey="PageResource1" uiculture="auto" Debug="true" %>
```

This is what's in my /knowledgebase/ directory:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" ValidateRequest="false" 
Inherits="YAF.ForumPageBase" culture="auto" uiculture="auto" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="YAF" Assembly="YAF" Namespace="YAF" %>
<script runat="server">
```

Is it somehow possible to use, for instance, homepage.master in the /knowledgebase/ directory?  If so, how would I accomplish this?  Thanks for any guidance anybody can offer!